# 2D Game graphics in native Java: Canvas vs. JComponent

Tags: java, swing, canvas, graphics, graphics2d

Apparently there are multiple ways of drawing game graphics in Java. All of them seem reasonable, yet I can't find out which way is the "best" way in terms of speed/efficiency:

Using the Canvas class (I):

- Game is an instance of `Canvas` or contains one
- Manipulate an `int` array representing the colors of each pixel
- [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4&list=PL8CAB66181A502179) is an example for this method.

Using the canvas class (II):

- Game is an instance of `Canvas` or contains one
- Graphics/G2D object is used to draw onto the canvas
- Rest is similar to the first approach

Using a JLabel's paintComponent() method (How I'd do it):

- Game is an instance of `JLabel` (or any other suitable class) or contans one
- `repaint()` is called every frame
- Graphics/G2D draw methods are used to draw `BufferedImage`s or geometrical shapes onto the `JComponent`

Which one of these, if any, is the way to go? Or does the choice depend on what I want to make? 
 
 EDIT: I'm talking about a tile-based top-down game. The Binding Of Isaac is a good example. Furthermore, I don't want to use LWJGL/JOGL because I feel like I don't have enough experience with game programming itself to additionally learn any advanced graphics API. Maybe I'll look into LWJGL in the future but for now, native Java has to do the trick.

Comment: It's a question that's hard to answer, except for the "Well, that depends..." answer (which **could** in fact be useful, if elaborated properly!). One also has to be careful about the scope: At a higher level, one could argue whether you shouldn't use OpenGL (JOGL, LWJGL) for a game anyhow, so this question is already targeted at 2D games, and presumably also to "realtime" games with lots of animations (i.e. rather a jump'n'run than a chess UI...).

Comment: Added some explanations to clarify my question.